# post values from javascript to php and add those values in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

arraytest.html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="go to php" onclick="show()">
<br><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = new Array(6,5);
function show(){
   $.ajax({        
    type: "POST",
    url: "arra.php",
    data: {test : JSON.stringify(a)},
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success" +data);
        }
    }); 
}
</script>
```

arra.php

```
<?php 
$arr = json_decode($_POST['test'], true);
$v = $arr[0] + arr[1] ;
echo $v ; 
?>
```

i couldn't add the array values in php file. anybody could help me with this ?
am getting the error as:
Parse error: syntax error,unexpected '[' in c:\wamp\www\arra.php on line  *3*

Comment: What problem are you having? The PHP looks fine. The only issue I can see is that the `success:` function doesn't display the response anywhere.

Comment: i coudn't add the array values in php that has posted from javascript. how could i make that ?

Comment: Why do you think you couldn't add them?

Comment: data in the succes function shows parse error and syntax error on line "$v = $arr[0] + arr[1] ;"

Comment: Please post the exact error message in the questin.

Comment: You're missing a `$` on arr[1].

Comment: ooph. silly one. thanks man. that worked (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success function isn't showing the response. The callback function should take an argument, and then do something with it.

```
function show(){
    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
        url: "arra.php",
        data: {test : a},
        success: function(response) {
            alert("success, the answer is: " + response);        
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to $_POST. notice you are sending POST.

```
<?php 
    $arr = $_POST['test'];
    $v = $arr[0] + $arr[1];
    echo $v; 
?>
```

Comment: `$_REQUEST` contains everything that's in `$_POST` and `$_GET`. Why don't you think it will work?

Comment: i coudn't add the array values in php that has posted from javascript. how could i make that ?